# Design problem- one function calls all three

Tags: c++

```
class Feature{};

class IFat
{
   //init feature for IFat

   vector<Feature> vf;
};
class IThin
{
   //init feature for IThin
   vector<Feature> vf;
};

class ISlim
{
    //init feature for ISlim
    vector<Feature> vf;
};

void func(IFeature_Vector)
{
     //accessing vf depending on IFeature_Vector passed in
}
```

I would like to know if there is a nice neat way to make one func that can call each instance without having to call three times for each case. I'm sorry to say this that I know this is a jurasic problem but I just can't think up a good solution while I am so much crazy for it. I hope you understand my problem. I am thankful if you could help.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you need to provide more info.

Comment: We don't know what `// init feature for IWhatever` means, or what "nice neat way to make one func that can call each instance without having to call three times for each case" means.

Comment: "call each instance" does not make any sense. Can you rephrase?

Comment: guys, it is so complicated? He don't wants to write three overloaded versions of `void func( ... )`

Comment: @Thomas I guess we mortals find it hard to understand someone who says things like "i think I am not sitting here chuckling my binary activities"

Comment: @Seth don't know what he wanted to tell me with that sentence, but a look at the code was helpfull to understand. I'm trainer at work, so i have to guess every day: "What he want's?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at `template` programming in C++. Here is a good explanation: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

You could write something like

```
template<class T> void func(T myVector) { ... };
```

Comment: Yes, it seems similar like that. As long as it is as normal as this, i think I am not sitting here chuckling my binary activities