# template function and vector accessing

Tags: c++, oop, templates, vector

[Design problem- one function calls all three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129262/design-problem-one-function-calls-all-three)

I continuation from another question after that thread, here is what I try:

```
template<class T>
void func(T* p)
{
   p->
}
```

I am stuck after that arrow as I don't know how to access each element of the which vector I passed in? The `func` receives argument as a switch case, I have solved it but the code inside all repeated except the vector. :-(

I am new about template, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
void func(T*p)
{
   (*p)[0]; // the first element of the passed-in vector (or array)
}
```

Comment: This..is..just..so..useful! Thank you :-D